# Using a mutable default argument, how to access the object from outside the function?

Tags: python, function, arguments, mutable

If I have something like this:

```py
def f(x, cache=[]):
    cache.append(x)
```

How can I access `cache` from outside `f`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`__defaults__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) magic:

```
>>> def f(x, cache=[]):
...     cache.append(x)
>>> f.__defaults__
([],)
>>> f(2)
>>> f.__defaults__
([2],)
>>> f('a')
>>> f.__defaults__
([2, 'a'],)
>>> c, = f.__defaults__
>>> c
[2, 'a']
```

Just for the sake of completeness, [`inspect.getfullargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec) can also be used, which is more explicit:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(f)
FullArgSpec(args=['x', 'cache'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=([2, 'a'],), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(f).defaults
([2, 'a'],)
```

Comment: I never considered looking at `__defaults__`, but this might make your code more "magic" where simple code is usually better.

Comment: True, but I don't think there's other way other than declaring global or using other modules.

Answer (score 1):

Variables inside of the function scope are not meant to be accessed outside.

What you should do is use a global variable to store your cache:

```
GLOBAL_CACHE = []

def f(x, cache=GLOBAL_CACHE):
    cache.append(x)
```

Comment: The only way to get a value of a variable from a function scope is if the variable is mutable and passed in as an argument, or if it's declared globally, or if it's returned by the function. Globals are never great, but that sounds like what you're asking for?

Comment: Sounds fair. You'll probably want to at least add a comment to your code as I wouldn't know what `f.__defaults__` does without googling for it!